# T-SQL Value from 1st select on each row in 2nd select of a union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Very simplified, my sql looks like this:

```
;with RawData as (
select from table1

union all

select from table2)

select * from rawdata
```

In the first select I get the On Hand quantity.  In the 2nd select that column is zero because I'm getting what's on order.  I want the On Hand quantity to repeat on each row.  So instead of

```
8
0
0
0
```

I would have

```
8
8
8
8
```

How do I do that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sum() over() as below:

```
;with RawData as (
...
)
select sum(yourcolumn) over() from RawData
```

If you have specific id column then you can use

```
select sum(yourcolumn) over(partition by id) from RawData
```

Comment: Just to add, OP should mention and use a column for `order by` in partition, else he might get `0,0,0,8` or `0,0,8,8` etc as well.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Works perfectly, thanks!!